# Anti-CSRF approach in chat application where textarea is rendered once

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, security, symfony

I am integrating chat application in my website. Chat boxes are managed using a javascript library. They are HTML components to which I append a textarea where the user enters the message to be sent (Facebook-like style of chat).

The messages exchanged are persisted in a MySQL databases. Server side language is PHP under Symfony2 framework.

How can I secure my database in this case? Normally, to prevent CSRF vulnerability, I generate a CSRF token when the form containing textarea is rendered. Symfony2  helps to easily validate against the token. But in my situation, textarea is used without a form. I can wrap my textarea inside a form with hidden input token field, but I don't think it will be appropriate to render a new form (with new token) whenever a new message need to be sent.

Could you please share with me your insights regarding such issue? Are there any tricks for chat applications to prevent CSRF attacks? Any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just use strip_tags() in the PHP code?

Comment: CSRF and XSS are different things. A CSRF token can't guard against XSS (in and of itself.

Comment: @SamuilBanti, thank you for your quick feedback. can strip_tags() replace the mechanism of CSRF token?

Comment: @DanSingerman, I see that I am probably wrong in terminology, but my goal is to keep the same role that CSRF token plays in forms.

Comment: The use of `strip_tags` doesn't sound like ideal advice to me to protect against XSS - what if users are discussing HTML? You'll wreck what they are saying. Just use `htmlentities()` on your output.

Comment: @halfer, thanks. Does this function able to replace the mechanism brought by CSRF token?

Comment: No, you changed the topic of your question after I started writing my comment. Assuming you are using AJAX, you could obtain a new CSRF token from the server every time you submit, and store this in a hidden field. That will give you a token to send to the server, and to check during the save process.

Comment: @halfer, okey! If I completely understand, there is no other way to replace this mechanism. Then, I should get asynchronously the new token value from server and modify the value of hidden field (with javascript). After submit I should validate against this value, generate a new one and send back to browser to update hidden field. Am I right?  thanks again

Comment: If you are trying to protect against third-party websites and tools posting in your JavaScript-based form, yes. You don't have to use a hidden field but it's a good/common way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The important features of an [anti-CSRF token](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#General_Recommendation:_Synchronizer_Token_Pattern) are that:

1. Each user must have a different token.  (A user might also have several tokens for different purposes, but no two users may share a token.)
2. It must not be practical for a malicious user to obtain (or construct) a valid token for another user.
3. Each request (that could have unwanted effects if done maliciously) must include a token.
4. The server must not accept the request unless it contains a valid token for the user performing the request.

Requirements 1 and 2 are typically implemented either using a cryptographic [message authentication code](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) to generate the tokens, or simply by assigning a randomly generated token to each user (or session) and storing a copy of it on the server.

For traditional HTML forms, one way to implement requirement 3 is to include the token as a hidden field in the form.  However, that's not the only way to do this.  In particular, if you're submitting requests by Ajax, all you need is to have your Ajax code somehow obtain the token (e.g. from a hidden field, or an HTML `data` attribute, or simply from a piece of JS code somewhere on the page) and include it in the request.

---

For example, if you look at the HTML source of this Stack Overflow page you're reading right now, you'll find a piece of JavaScript that looks something like this (un-minified):

```
<script>
    StackExchange.init({
        "locale": "en",
        // ...snip....
        "site": {
            "name": "Stack Overflow",
            // ...snip....
        },
        "user": {
            "fkey": "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef",
            // ...snip....
        }
    });
    // ...snip...
</script>
```

The `user.fkey` value (which, for obvious reasons, I've changed above) is a random 128-bit anti-CSRF token that is stored in the `StackExchange` JS object, and is included in every Ajax request made by the scripts on the page.

Answer (score 2):

One method would be to use a counter approach.

So on first form render, you include a token. Each response includes that token and an incrementing counter (starting at a random number). After the first request, you know on the backend which counter position is valid, and can invalidate the token if you find an invalid counter position. Then after 100 (or 1000 or whatever) requests, force a token refresh (which does a normal request to get a new token).

So the convo would look like:

```
Client                       Server
getToken --------------------->
                             generate new token
     <-----------------------token // x4asf3%2f
generateCounter() // 2332523
sendText(text)
{text: text, token: token, counter: counter+1}
    -------------------------->
                              if (!isValidToken(token)) error()
                              saveCounter(token, counter)
                              doSomethingWithText(text)
sendText(text)
    -------------------------->
                              if (!isValidToken(token)) error()
                              if (counter != getCounter(token)+1) error()
                              doSomethingWithText(text)
```

This is similar to the syn-ack process that TCP uses.